# Newsletter content not displaying upon queue

Tags: magento

My magento version is 1.4.1.1.

This is my problem…

I added a newsletter template, completed all the fields, added data into the content box and then saved the template.

Then I changed to the status to queue.

When this newsletter displays where I can enter in a queue date, I noticed that the content box completed earlier is now empty. 
The other fields have the data I entered earlier.

I have tested this issue a number of times with the same result.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution listed here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/199826/#t267878

It worked for me, I'm using 1.4.1.1 as well.